# Ubuntu can not login after init

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I executed the command "init" from terminal while I am in GUI mode. Unfortunately now I can not login to my account via GUI. It bounces back to login screen when I try to log in via GUI. However I am able to

- Log in to my account via terminal (Alt + Ctr + Fn)
- Log in to guest user account via GUI

Comment: This is after a restart right?

Comment: Yes this is after restart. No GUI appears after init, so had to restart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the solution that worked for me. I found this from [launchpad.net/](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+question/197479)

```
Press CTRL+ALT+F1 and log in there and run:

sudo chown -R $USER:$USER $HOME (this may take time)

Then press CTRL+ALT+F7 and try to log in
```